# Can I reset private static variable or reset application from XCTest code?

Tags: swift, xctest, xctestcase

I am testing a framework. 
Every test case set static variable and it looks like `XCTest` shares static area of a framework.
As a result, running tests at the same time makes test failure from the second test.
Note that running tests individually makes all test succeed.

I am testing with Unit test not UI test, but should I reset App at the stage of `class tearDown()`?
If so, please tell me how to do it, because
`XCUIApplication.terminate()` fails in the subclass of `XCTestCase`.

I am using Xcode 11 Swift 5.1

Comment: What are your static variables, and what are they for? How are your tests setting them? Please add code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for are the *instance methods*, not the *type methods.*

Furthermore, consider `setUp` over `tearDown`:

Here is the description for the *instance method* `setUp` from Apple's documentation:

> Before each test begins, XCTest calls setUpWithError(), followed by setUp(). **Override this method to reset state for each test** method. If state preparation might throw errors, override setUpWithError().

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctest/1500341-setup

Example usage:

```
override func setUp() {
    // reset state for each test
}
```

For comparison, here is the description for the *type method* `setUp` from Apple's documentation:

> The setUp() class method is called exactly once for a test case, before its first test method is called. **Override this method to customize the initial state for all tests** in the test case.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1496262-setup

Example usage:

```
override class func setUp() {
    // customize the initial state for all tests
}
```

I don't know what the purpose of your static variables are, but it sounds like they are responsible for changing behavior in your app. I recommend using mock objects and/or data. I would consider looking into writing "testable code." It will help you keep your code clean and also make it easier for you to write unit tests. It is also object-oriented.